# Convergence of QR method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

How does the number of iterations for QR-method for eigenvalues to converge depend on the matrix size $n$?

I ran a MATLAB code for $n$ from 10 to 400 and the number of iterations before convergence does increase, but I can't seem to find any analytical approximations of such growth rate.

Comment: Interesting question.

Comment: I think I saw the runtime given as $O(n^3|\log\epsilon|)$ (for shifted QR with matrix block split whenever a sub-diagonal element gets small enough) where $\epsilon$ is the accuracy of the eigenvalues. Note that Matlab employs more advanced algorithms incorporating multi-shift and bulk-chasing which can approximate several eigenvalue clusters in parallel, greatly reducing the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

For a Hermitian or symmetric matrix, the time to compute the eigenvalues is dominated by time to reduce the matrix to tridiagonal form: approximately $4n^3/3$ floating point operations.

Since the convergence of shifted QR is at least quadratic (and usually cubic), each eigenvalue can be computed to machine precision in a number of iterations of the QR decomposition independent of $n.$  So the number of iterations is $O(n)$ (a constant number times the number of eigenvalues). This answers your question for the Hermitian case.

Since a QR decomposition of a tridiagonal matrix can be computed in $O(n)$ floating point operations, the total time for computing eigenvalues after reducing to tridiagonal form is $O(n^2)$ floating point operations.

See "Numerical Linear Algebra" by Trefethen and Bau for details.

For a non-symmetric matrix, Francis's double-shift algorithm is used on a reduction of the matrix to upper Hessenberg form.    The convergence rate of the double-shift algorithm is usually quadratic, so the number of iterations will still be a constant times the number of eigenvalues (in other words, $O(n)$).  However, since the QR decomposition of an upper Hessenberg matrix takes approximately $6n^2$ operations, more time will be spent on the iterative part of the algorithm than on the reduction to Hessenberg form.  See David S. Watkins's paper on Francis's algorithm for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for the reference. It's just that one question in my homework, namely to find any pattern between the matrix size and the number of iterationsit takes to converge. So I figured it is almost linear for small $n$ and as $n$ becomes large (400 in my case) we get a **very** different picture.

Comment: Are you considering the number of iterations of QR decomposition or the total time to compute the eigenvalues?  As stated in the first sentence, the total time to compute the eigenvalues is $O(n^3).$